# I need to create stored proceder to in T-SQL and exec it from daily job to notify the admin if there are any results back

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've written this so far. I am not sure what is the best way to create a SP and then execute it from daily jobs, and from there I can configure to notify me if there are any results.

I was hoping if someone can point me in the right direction since this does not seem to be working for me. For testing purposes, I've added If/else clause and excec sp_send_dbmail but I don't get an email where there is value more than 0, but I get notification via email if there is no result returns.

I don't want to hardcode email to in the SP. I want to do select recipients from the daily job. Now my challenge is that can I even do it? Can I run SP in job, and let the job determine if there is result then send out an email if not then do nothing

```
    Create PROCEDURE PendingTime
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @recordCount int

      SELECT
        @recordCount = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0),
          employee_name,
          entry_empl_uno,
          COUNT(*),
          MIN(post_date),
          MAX(post_date),
          MIN(tran_date),
          MAX(tran_date)
    FROM TableA With (nolock)
    INNER JOIN TableB (nolock)
      ON entry_empl_uno = empl_uno
    WHERE entry_status = 'n' -- and post_date>=dateadd(month,-2,getdate())

      IF (@recordCount > 0)
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'DB Mail',
                             @recipients = 'ABCD@XYZ.com',
                             @query = 'SELECT
                             @recordCount = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0),
          employee_name,
          entry_empl_uno,
          COUNT(*),
          MIN(post_date),
          MAX(post_date),
          MIN(tran_date),
          MAX(tran_date)
    FROM TableA With (nolock)
    INNER JOIN TableB (nolock)
      ON entry_empl_uno = empl_uno
    WHERE entry_status = 'n'
    GROUP BY employee_name,
    ENTRY_EMPL_UNO',
                              @subject = 'Test',
                              @Body = 'Test',
                              @attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
      END
    END;
```

Comment: `employee_name`,`entry_empl_uno` need aggregate functions or `group by` on them